# Onclick should close other opened element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do have 2 elements in my page which i want to show them when user clicks on 2 different buttons.

Here is my code

```
$('.social-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');
});

$('.social-toggle1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');
});
```

When user clicks on the first button, the first element will be show up, but i want either user clicks on the second button or one of the links in the opened-menu the first opened menu be closed.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y9as9ntg/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to write two different event here. Use comma seprated multiple selector for targetting both button:

```
$('.social-toggle,.social-toggle1').on('click', function() {
  $('.social-networks').not($(this).next()).removeClass('open-menu');
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1fr85wf8/)**

Comment: Thanks! How it works if i have 3 or 4 elements then?

Comment: @Amir: yes it will. but dont give different classes to them. keep unique class so that you can target all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/y9as9ntg/2/) is the code what you want. You didnt removed the class which was applied previously.

```
$('.social-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.social-toggle1').next().removeClass('open-menu');
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');

});

$('.social-toggle1').on('click', function() {
    $('.social-toggle').next().removeClass('open-menu');
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open-menu');
});
```